# Tables are not updated in SQLITE db in Windows Phone Dev

Tags: windows-phone-7, sqlite

I have an existing sqlite database in my Windows Phone 7.1 Project. I am able to execute select query on the Database...But I am unable to execute insert or update query on the tables in the db. For Example I run the following:

```
//Update operation
    public void Update<T>(string statement) where T : new()
    {
        try
        {
            Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = db.CreateCommand(statement);
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("updation failed: " + ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

This executes absolutely fine and No Exception is thrown, indicating update is successful. but when I see the database, I get old records not the updated ones. I have cross verified the query by running it in SQLITE browser and it works fine. But when I run through the app, it does not. I get 1 when nonQuery statement executes, meaning record is updated. but unfortunately it is not.

Any help regarding this is appreciated. Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the commit transaction code. By default, the transactions are rolled back.

Also, are you aware of [DatabaseSchemaUpdater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.data.linq.databaseschemaupdater%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class? [Here's the sample](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Local-Database-Schema-Upgrade-Part1---Adding-new-columns) I've used to upgrade the DB schema in my application, works good. The article is about adding columns, however the class has AddTable<…> method  as well. Don't forget to read the 2-nd comment as well.